# meaning of ことに?

Tags: particle-に

> お土産を気に入ってくれたことに安堵すると、

What is the meaning of ことに ? This is something I see from time to time, but I don't understand its pattern. Aren't ことは or ことを working here ?

Comment: So in short, it would mean : "When she felt relieved BECAUSE her gift pleased her," Am I correct in my understanding of に ?

Comment: @Ushiroyama Yes! This type of に is commonly used with expressions that describe feelings.

Comment: I'm back to this thread because I would like confirmation that this phrase uses the same ことに as the one in my question : > それに顔をしかめるのは、当主様に失礼といつも思いつつも、条件反射的にそうしてしまう**ことに**、彼女はいつも自己嫌悪していた…。If so, it would be : "Because she does that, she always hated herself." ?